# Full-width CSS header not scrolling correctly with narrow browser window

Tags: html, css, gwt, header, scroll

I have a header that is 100% in width and content that doesn't have a minimum or maximum size.
When I make my browser window rather small and then scroll it the header doesn't fill 100%. It is only the size of my browser window even if the content under it is much bigger.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5782.png

I cannot use max-width or min-width.

Comment: A link to the site or some actual code would be very helpful since without that, it is very difficult to tell what is actually happening.

Comment: I am not allowed to do that. The image I gave you is off another topic.

Answer (score 0):

When you start setting the width of banners from my experience things don't always happen as you want them to. My suggestion to you would be to set a div for that banner area with a black background then convert your banner to a transparent image. That way you can set the dimensions of the image to the exact size needed to keep your links visible and it will appear to "blend" with the background as 1 whole image. This way it won't matter what size the window is your banner will always be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Set a container with width attribute set. If you don't it will be interpreted as 100% of how much you can see when you load page. So it will not fill the rest of the area.